# Why I got 'unknown size' error when I use '=default' for the destructor?

Tags: c++11

**Inner.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

class Outter
{
public:
    Outter();
    ~Outter() = default;

private:
    class Inner;
    std::vector<Inner> list;
};
```

**Inner.cpp**

```
#include "Inner.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class Outter::Inner
{
public:
    Inner() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
    ~Inner() {}
private:
    int x, y, z;
};

Outter::Outter()
{
    std::cout << "Constructor\n";
}

//Outter::~Outter()
//{
//    std::cout << "Destructor\n";
//}
```

**InnerMain.cpp**

```
#include "Inner.hpp"

int main()
{
    Outter test;
}
```

When I compile above codes, I got an 'unknown size' error for the class Outter::Inner.

But if I change the 'default' destructor of Outter class to the implementation in Inner.cpp (commented in the above), then the error is cleared.

Why does this happen when I use '=default' destructor?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

---

As a result, in this case, '=default' was not important.
The implementation should be placed in .cpp file to make the compiler know the size of class Outter::Inner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forward declaration is not enough here. `std::vector` needs to know exactly what is the size of the inner class at compile time. Actually, the `std::vector` destructor who needs to know what is the real size of the inner class.

You have some solutions like using pointers to `Inner` class (if you want to keep your destructor in hpp):

```
std::vector<Inner*> list;
```

Or alternatively, move your destructor to the cpp class like what you did in the commented code. BTW, please be aware that you can set your destructor to `default` in the cpp file:

```
Outter::~Outter()=default;
```

---

> Why does this happen when I use '=default' destructor?

Because of the destructor of `std::vector` needs to know the size. You defined the destructor of the class containing the `std::vector` in the header file where no information about the real size of the `inner`. However, when you put the definition of the destructor in the cpp file, the compiler now knows what is the actual size of `inner` and `std::vector` destructor will not complain.

Comment: You're right. But what I want to know is why it is different if I use '=default' destructor or not. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you like to sugget some materials for the detail information (or knowlege) such as urls or books?